# Sort values in entity framework based on substring values from a column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have Department table values in EF model and one of the column has value has value values like DEPTName YEAR-EMPid 'ACCT 2020-012', 'SVC 2021-014', 'MRKT 2022-001'  . How do I sort to get values in the below order in EF using LINQ. The prefix for department is sometimes 3 or 4

'MRKT 2022-001'
'SVC 2021-014'
'ACCT 2020-012'

Please advise.

var depPrefix ='XYZ "

var rs = qry.select(x=> new DeptDto { DeptId = x.DeptId , Dep = x.Dep,  DeptEmp=x.Dep.SubString(0, x.Dep.Length -    depPrefix.length)});

The above works well with prefix has only 3 dept abbreviation; but fails when more/less than 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use IComparable

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] input = {"MRKT 2022-001", "SVC 2021-014", "ACCT 2020-012"};

            var results = input.Select(x => new MyCompare(x)).OrderByDescending(x => x).Select(x => x.input).ToArray();


        }
        public class MyCompare : IComparable<MyCompare>
        {
            public string input { get; set; }
            string prefix { get; set; }
            int year { get; set; }
            int suffix { get; set; }
            const string pattern = @"^(?'prefix'[^\s]+)\s+(?'year'\d{4})-(?'suffix'.*)";
            public MyCompare(string input)
            {
                this.input = input;
                Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
                prefix = match.Groups["prefix"].Value;
                year = int.Parse(match.Groups["year"].Value);
                suffix = int.Parse(match.Groups["suffix"].Value);
            }
            public int CompareTo(MyCompare other)
            {
                if (this.year != other.year)
                    return this.year.CompareTo(other.year);
                if (this.prefix != other.prefix)
                    return this.prefix.CompareTo(other.prefix);
                return this.suffix.CompareTo(other.suffix);
            }


        }
```